# RuntimeError: At least one choice needs to be made for complete functioning of this sample

Tags: python, azure

I am new to IoT and am using it for the first time for a project. I started with some basics of Microsoft Azure pnp from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-pnp/quickstart-connect-device?pivots=programming-language-python

Now, when I try running 'simple_thermostat.py' from this:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/master/azure-iot-device/samples/pnp

I get the following error:

"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_thermostat.py", line 337, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "simple_thermostat.py", line 253, in main
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: At least one choice needs to be made for complete functioning of this sample.
```

"

Can someone explain me the problem and the solution as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed through the code sourced @ https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/pnp/simple_thermostat.py

Highlighting only the important lines of the code which is responsible for the above  observed error.

```
switch = os.getenv("IOTHUB_DEVICE_SECURITY_TYPE")
    if switch == "DPS":
        provisioning_host = (
            .
            .
            .
            .

    elif switch == "connectionString":
        conn_str = os.getenv("IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING")
        
    else:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "At least one choice needs to be made for complete functioning of this sample."
        )
```

The issue is occurring because the `IOTHUB_DEVICE_SECURITY_TYPE` is not provided

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/tree/master/azure-iot-device/samples/pnp), before running the sample you will have the environment variable `IOTHUB_DEVICE_SECURITY_TYPE`

[image]

Comment: I have actually set the IOTHUB_DEVICE_SECURITY_TYPE beforehand in the environment variables, but still am facing the error!

Comment: Just a thought - you could by pass the usage of the Environment Variable - rather use the below code `switch ="DPS"` ( or Security Type as per the mentioned in above screenshot)

Comment: Actually, using the connection string for the authentication gave me an error for some reason, but the DPS enrollment group solved the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Encountered similar issue. It was because we were using Powershell to set the environment variables.

For powershell:

```
$Env:IOTHUB_DEVICE_SECURITY_TYPE = "connectionString" 
    
$Env:IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING="<your connection string>"
```